# Control to select data source on Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, json

I am building a map using leaflet.

My data source looks something like this:

```
var districts = 
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": 
[

{"type":"Feature",
"geometry":
{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[ [-75.228404,40.084708],[-75.2286,40.084875],[-75.230501,40.086024]//...
]]] 
},
"properties":{"dist_num":"8", "gender":"M", "party":"democrat"}},


{"type":"Feature",
"geometry":
{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[ [-75.227985,40.084356],[-75.2281,40.0843],[-75.228241,40.084198],//...
]]] 
},
"properties":{"dist_num":"5", "gender":"F", "party":"republican"}}, //....

];
```

I've got a working map that shows districts by party (democrat/republican) using this javascript:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([39.955, -75.1647], 11);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

var geojson;

function getColor(d) {
    return d == 'Democrat' ? 'blue' :
           d == 'Republican'  ? 'red':
              '#FFEDA0';
}

function style(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.party),
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.3
    };
}

L.geoJson(districts, {style: style}).addTo(map);
```

Now I want to add a control where the user can switch from the `fillColor` in the `function style` from political party to display by gender. Does Leaflet have a built in method to do this? Or do I need to build my own in HTML/Javascript/Jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your style function to accept another parameter, and use that to set your style.  When the user wants to change the rendering, you just call **.setStyle(feature, color)**.  You will also need to create a function to define the colors for that dataset as well. For example, I'm using a function name of getGenderColor().

Example:

```
function style(feature, fillColor) {
    return {
        fillColor : fillColor,
        ....
    }
}
var geojson = L.geoJson(districts, {style: function (f) {
    return style(f, getColor(f.properties.party));
}}).addTo(map);

$("#button-to-render").on('click', function () {
    geojson.setStyle(function (f) {
        return style(f, getGenderColor(f.properties.gender));
    });
});
```

There are other ways to do this, but I think this example will work for what you need.

I created a simple example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TnX96/103/

Comment: Thanks - this does almost what I want it to.  In the end I'm going to have a few buttons on my map, to view by gender, party, age, race, etc.  That part I've now got working.  The problem is with the mouseout feature which calls resetStyle -- it resets to the original set style, not the button set style.  I'm not that great with JS/Jquery so I'm not sure where to make that happen.  (The mouseout question wasn't in my original sample b/c I wanted to keep that code simple but I do have it in my app.)